# Passing objects of any type to Hadoop Mapper

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The hadoop configuration object only allows string as value in the set method

set(String name, String value)

Is there an easy way to set any other object types ? I would like to retrieve these objects in the mapper.

I noticed that in version 0.15 or so, there was a set(String key, Object value) method which has since been deprecated and removed. Any reason why this was done ? Is there any other way for me to pass an object to the mapper ?

Comment: How 'big' are the objects you're trying to pass around?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration object has to be serialized to a string and sent to the mappers as a file with strings in it.
You need to provide a way to serialize and deserialize your objects.